# rails beginner, created 2 rails app on local dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I was able to install rails (3.2.3, ruby v1.9.3), then created a test app:

$ rails new Hello

then I cd'd into the new directory 'hello' and did the following commands:

```
$ rails generate controller home index
$ rails s
$ rake routes, it gave me
home_index GET /home/index(.:format) home#index
     hello     /hello(.:format)      Hello#index
```

Then I pointed my browser to: http://localhost:3000/home/index - and it worked great.

Then I wanted to begin a tutorial and it asked me to create a new rails application

so I did like I did before...

```
$ rails new TutorialApp
$ rails generate controller tutorial index
$ rails s
$ rake routes, it gave me

tutorial_index GET /tutorial/index(.:format) tutorial#index
```

then I pointed my browser to: http://localhost:3000/tutorial/index, it gave me a message of

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/tutorial/index" Try running rake routes for
>   more information on available routes.

So I ran rake routes again, which it gave me the same output as it did before

```
tutorial_index GET /tutorial/index(.:format) tutorial#index
```

Since I created that first rails app "Hello", do I need to turn off that app before starting the new rails app "Tutorial" or they can both be running at the same time?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run rails server ("rails s"), you're typically running it in the context of the rails project you're in at the time, so before beginning a new project, I would shut down the current server (CTRL C). Also, make sure you create a new rails app in a folder is isn't itself at the root of a rails app. It looks like you might have created your tutorial app inside the root of your Hello app. Sounds like those are the two main things that tripped you up.

Comment: I have a rails_app directory that stores the different rails apps, I have two folders in the directory: hello and tutorial. I cd'd out of the hello directory before I did rails new tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I did ctrl-c and tried localhost:3000/tutorial/index and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a different port

```
rails server -p 3001
```

It will run in a different port. Then, just point to http://localhost:3001

But usually you will probably stop the server on one app and start the other one. It's up to you.